# Login to Bank via Python Requests

Tags: javascript, python, html, web

I've been looking into logging in to my bank (Westpac AU) through python requests and retrieving some transaction data. I've combed through the web and stackoverflow and whilst many aim for the same goal, I don't believe I haven't seen anyone providing much detail on whether it's actually possible.

The bank in question uses Javascript and it looks they use Fiserv services to encrypt(?) certain information. They do not have an API either (for personal use).

Here's my current code (though is quite amateurish, I'm only currently experimenting) -

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
"""
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge, EdgeOptions


options = EdgeOptions()
options.use_chromium = True

driver = Edge(options = options)
"""


EAM_URL = "https://banking.westpac.com.au/eam/servlet/getEamInterfaceData"
LOGIN_URL = "https://banking.westpac.com.au/wbc/banking/handler?TAM_OP=login&segment=personal&logout=false"
SUBMIT_URL = 'https://banking.westpac.com.au/eam/servlet/AuthenticateHttpServlet'

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36 Edg/92.0.902.55",
           }

data = {"username":"", "password","halgm","brand","__RequestVerificationToken","guidID"}

with HTMLSession() as session:
    login_req = session.get(LOGIN_URL, cookies={}
                            )
    eam1 = session.get(EAM_URL)
    eam2 = session.get(EAM_URL)
    print(dict(login_req.cookies))
```

I don't really know where to start either.

This is my last try before I experiment with Selenium, so I thought I'd see if anyone knows.
Thanks.

Comment: If certain parts of the webpage's business logic has a hard dependency on JavaScript, then whatever that is will need to be executed to generate whatever appropriate tokens needed to continue with access through a JavaScript runtime.  Short answer is Selenium is more suitable.

Comment: @metatoaster right. So do you think it may be doable through Java/JS? Or perhaps integrating a js script into the python script? (I don't know if that's possible)

Comment: It's certainly not impossible to incorporate a JavaScript runtime (Java is a whole other unrelated platform to this discussion) such as Node.js or Spidermonkey that the Python script would manually invoke, but do realize that there will be other objects (such as `window` and the whole DOM) which must be provided or emulated by those runtime, which is available for free without additional work through a browser controlled through Selenium.  However I will agree that Selenium is heavy and has other drawbacks.

Comment: Have you tried woob (https://woob.tech/)?